# Bootstrap Icons not displaying properly in IOS device

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, icons

Can anyone help me in resolving the bootstrap icons on IOS devices? The below screenshot shows how it is displaying in iOS.

[image]

When I refresh the page it is back to normal bootstrap.

I have changed the relative path for icon-font-path but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: and your code ?

Comment: It is in react and I have no access to share the code. I used span tag with bootstrap glyphicons classes. It appears only when user visit for the first time using IOS device.

Answer (score 0):

You should try font-awesome...